# Illustrator: how to create a pattern brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, brush

I am attempting to make a simple pattern brush with five b&w rectangles, with no success. Each time I drag the artwork to the brush swatch and i get the message seen below. I have tried various things like deleting some of the objects, but it fails except where there is one square white rectangle.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to create a brush out of? It looks like a single object to me (rather than 5 rectangles)

Comment: Hi Cai as I say I am a novice so bear with me. I made a white square then  added three black rectangles. This is the small object on the left.

Comment: If you're only selecting rectangles then you shouldn't have a problem. Look in the layers panel and make sure there isn't anything else accidentally selected too (I was accidentally guides and getting the same error yesterday, took me a while to figure that out)

Comment: Will do and thanks for your input its lonely out here learning online!

Comment: Sadly not the case. I have since made the rectangles using the pen tool but still encounter the same error message. Yet if I draw a square and follow the same procedure it allows me to make a pattern brush. Odd and perplexing. I guess this is the hard way to learn. Any other clues?

Comment: Do your rectangles have any appearance attributes, effects, gradients or anything other than basic solid fill or stroke?

Comment: Well Cai none other than a fill. So trial and error eventually got me there though its beats the crap out of me why. I repeated the exercise with just black rectangles no white and it worked. I think therefore that it can only be a single colour for it to work which now thinking on makes sense. Nice though to know there are people out there patient enough and willing to help. Have a great weekend. Gerard.

Comment: @Gerard29 Check my answer/example. You should really give it another go cause white artwork or single color artwork has nothing to do with it. You can have whatever/as many colors as you like.

Comment: @Gerard29 you can use as many colours as you like, you most likely had some appearance attribute that wasn't allowed, not sure. Using "expand" and "expand appearance" should sort it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you did wrong the last time but I can assure you, white artwork or multi-color artwork has nothing to do with it...You can have whatever/as many colors as you like.

You should give it one more try.

Look here :

[image]

> *Part of the old answer:*

You should also try using **Options -> Expand [or Expand Appearance]**. This will help if you have any unsupported attributes.

Comment: You should leave the original "expand" part in the answer

Comment: Thank you Alin. The mind is a lonely hunter working in isolation its easy to make things up. I have progressed but really appreciate your input thank you.

Comment: Additionally Alin I tried to adapt my artwork to produce an animated GIF. The work based purely on objects created with the pattern brush (well one a circle copied and scaled numerously). When I moved the file to Photoshop as a PSD with layers to achieve this all I could see was each layer showing the brush pattern populating the stroked circle not the finished artwork in each layer. Should I expand each circle or create and object of each circle maybe you know? Thanks in advance. Gerard.

Comment: @Gerard29 I may be able to help you but in order to understand your issue I really need to see the AI layer panel and PS layer panel. You imported your layers from AI to PS ? The layer panels from the two don't behave the same.

Comment: Thanks Alin I hit a major problem with this file its too large I need to learn a few more of the fundamentals before I start getting too adventurous I will be back on this once I get a handle on where I am going wrong. Have a smashing weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 circle small medium and bigger and select 3 circle and click on new brush > New brush pattern brush click ok
Make a circle remove the color and click on the stroke new brush created
[image]

Comment: Apologies Atek I just saw this thank you for the time it took you to provide this very useful working tip. Much appreciated. Gerard.